# Deactivating a user related to Service Resource

Tags: servicecloud, documentation, release-bug

This [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fs_resource_guidelines.htm&type=5) states

> Deactivating a user deactivates the related service resource.

while [this one](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_salesforce_scheduler_object_fields_service_resource.htm&type=5) states

> Deactivating a user doesn’t deactivate the related service resource.

With summer '22 release scheduled shortly, I'm seeing the former behavior in non-preview instances and latter behavior in preview instances. I'm confused if this is related to release preview or whether one of the SF documentations is incorrect. or am I completely missing out assigning some feature on the user account to even test this out? BTW, I've tried this out in multiple sandbox and checked the debug logs as well (nothing found in debug log files and no exceptions found). There are no triggers or flows or validation rules preventing this in my sandboxes.

FYI: I came across this problem while activating the user account related to service resource. The expected outcome i.e., corresponding service resource getting auto-activated didn't happen. But the overall problem/ confusion remains the same.

***Steps to replicate:***

- Create a user account or get an active user account.
- Create a service resource record and use the user account in the user lookup field.
- Deactivate the user account and check the active status on the service resource record.

Comment: I have reached out about this internally and will let you know if I have an update. Thx